# is not a valid value for date

Tags: spring, date, soap, jaxb

I'm using spring ws 2.0.2.RELEASE

I have a web service that creates a sales order

Two of the elements in the SOAP call are dates:

```
<ns3:requestedDate>2012-06-06T01:00:00.000+10:00</ns3:requestedDate>

<ns3:orderDate>2012-06-06T10:25:09.681+10:00</ns3:orderDate>
```

Both fields are defined in the schema as xs:dateTime

When I send through the SOAP call to my service I get:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>

     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>

     <faultstring xml:lang="en">Validation error</faultstring>

     <detail>

        <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2012-06-06T01:00:00.000+10:00' is not a valid value for 'date'.</spring-ws:ValidationError>

        <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '2012-06-06T01:00:00.000+10:00' of element 'ns3:requestedDate' is not valid.</spring-ws:ValidationError>

        <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2012-06-06T10:25:09.681+10:00' is not a valid value for 'date'.</spring-ws:ValidationError>

        <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '2012-06-06T10:25:09.681+10:00' of element 'ns3:orderDate' is not valid.</spring-ws:ValidationError>

     </detail>

  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Any idea why these valid dates are being reported as invalid by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if I pass in just the date portion '2012-06-06' it all works. I suppose the clue here should have been 'date' as opposed to 'datetime'. The end point being called must be expecting only a date.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the date format. It's parsing the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` but a lot of validators pass what is basically the universally accepted internet format of `DD-MM-YYYY`. Had similar trouble recently with validating a form in mobile safari. Try changing the date format and see if that works.

Comment: I tried with 06-06-2012T01:00:00.000+10:00 and got the same error

Comment: This is looking like a JAXB issue rather than a Spring issue directly

Comment: The date fields are defined by JAXB to be XMLGregorianCalendar which should be able to parse the dates as given. So I'm still confused why I'm getting this error.